# Python with Azure blob service

Tags: python, azure

i'm trying to use the Azure blob service to upload video files to the cloud.

I'm trying to figure what happens if my internet where to suddenly go out in the middle of a transfer.

There seems to be no Exceptions thrown when the internet go out.

```
from azure.common import AzureException
from azure.storage.blob import AppendBlobService, BlockBlobService, ContentSettings

    try:
        self.append_blob_service.append_blob_from_path(self.container_name, blob_name, upload_queue.get(timeout=3))
    except AzureException as ae:
        print("hey i caught something") <-- this line never seem to run
```

If i put the internet back on the blob seem to upload itself after about 30 minutes. I can't find any information about this in the docs. How long does the append_blob_from_path function keep trying?

Answer (score 0):

There is LinearRetry, ExponentialRetry, NoRetry and Custom Retry Policy.

The default is Linear which makes a max of 5 attempts 5 seconds apart. So if your net connection was down for < 25 seconds your upload will continue.

I am not sure if your internet connection was down for 30 mins. In that case it should have thrown and exception.

PS: You can look up the corresponding C# documentation for Retry policies.

Answer (score 0):

Python SDK for Azure Storage is OpenSource : https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python

If we look on calls from `append_blob_from_path()` we can see following things:

1. There is a default socket timeout:

```py
# Socket timeout in seconds
DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 20
```

2. At the end it uses functions from `StorageClient` (`AppendBlobService(BaseBlobService) -> BaseBlobService(StorageClient)`) and `StorageClient` uses :

```py
self.retry = ExponentialRetry().retry
```

3. `ExponentialRetry` has following constructor:

```py
def __init__(self, initial_backoff=15, increment_base=3, max_attempts=3,
                 retry_to_secondary=False, random_jitter_range=3):
        '''
        Constructs an Exponential retry object. The initial_backoff is used for 
        the first retry. Subsequent retries are retried after initial_backoff + 
        increment_power^retry_count seconds. For example, by default the first retry 
        occurs after 15 seconds, the second after (15+3^1) = 18 seconds, and the 
        third after (15+3^2) = 24 seconds.
        :param int initial_backoff: 
            The initial backoff interval, in seconds, for the first retry.
        :param int increment_base:
            The base, in seconds, to increment the initial_backoff by after the 
            first retry.
        :param int max_attempts: 
            The maximum number of retry attempts.
        :param bool retry_to_secondary:
            Whether the request should be retried to secondary, if able. This should 
            only be enabled of RA-GRS accounts are used and potentially stale data 
            can be handled.
        :param int random_jitter_range:
            A number in seconds which indicates a range to jitter/randomize for the back-off interval.
            For example, a random_jitter_range of 3 results in the back-off interval x to vary between x+3 and x-3.
        '''
```

4. Also there is a `RetryContext` which is used by this [_retry() function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/0a92c379a3de5b7b53d55d791a80851934729d88/azure-storage-common/azure/storage/common/retry.py#L123) to decide if retry is needed

If you enable [INFO-level logging](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python#logging) in your code, you will see all retries:

```py
# Basic configuration: configure the root logger, including 'azure.storage'
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(name)-20s %(levelname)-5s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

**To resume:**

You have (20 seconds of socket timeout + dynamic interval started from 15 seconds and randomly incremented each attempt) and you have 3 attempts. You can see what exactly happening when you enable INFO-level logging.